# Angular 5 HTTP get response error Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: json, http, angular5

I am working on Angular 5 with Http.

[image]

Getting this error while serve the application..

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-post-detail',
 templateUrl: './post-detail.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./post-detail.component.css']
})
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {
 body: string;
 recent: {};
 constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
 ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
   let userId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('userid');
   this.getUserPosts(userId);
   this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+id)
   .subscribe((data)=>{
    this.body = data.body;
   });
 }
}
```

I dont know Why I am getting this error and I assign the type as string in the class based on the syntax.

Response of API as below,

[image]

Comment: Did you really see the service is getting called in the network tab? I think it's not firing, better try to move service calls to injectable service and inject here in component.

Comment: Also the `body:string` change to `body:any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(data)=>{
    this.body = data.body;
}
```

`data` is not json. You need to run `.json()` on `data`. Or you could run `map` before subscribe:

```
 this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+id)
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe((data)=>{
      this.body = data.body;
 });
```

In order to use `map`, you need to import it:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

See more examples here: https://angular.io/api/http/Http

**EDIT**:

The response is typed - you need to create an interface for the response:

```
interface SomeResponse {
  Body: SomeType;
}
```

And make the request like this:

```
this.http.get<SomeResponse>'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+id)
  .subscribe((data)=>{
    this.body = data.body;
  });
```

Again, more examples here: https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular/

Comment: ERROR in src/app/frondend/posts/post-detail/post-detail.component.ts(27,21): error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: `import 'rxjs/Rx';`

Comment: @Jishad if you follow the example provided in EDIT, you no longer need .map(res => res.json()).

Comment: Its a best practice to put the interface to a separate file (eg. some-response.model.ts) so you can reuse the interface. In that case it will become: `export interface SomeResponse { ..}`  And: `import { SomeResponse } from './some-response.model'`